# Need advice on how to leverage WatchConnectivity to get one parameter from iphone in the background

Tags: swift, swift3, uikit, watchkit, watchconnectivity

I'm currently simply trying to a message from the watchKit app to the uiKit app which should respond with the data I need.

Any suggestions for how this should work? My attempt below...

---

I have this method on the UIKit side of my application (it's in my UIApplicationMain):

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
    print("received message from watch")
    syncDataBetweenDevices()
}
```

I want to send this message to the iphone:

```
func sendSignalToPhone(){
    self.wcSession.sendMessage(["msg" : "Watch needs deviceId"], replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
    print("Watch sent data to phone")
}
```

Comment: What does not work? Does the iPhone app receive the request? How do you initialize WatchConnectibity on the watch? See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465911/apple-watch-not-passing-data-to-iphone-swift/41740567#41740567